# FuncAnimation is unable to plot the data

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot, sensors

I am trying to read the data from a .csv file and plot it in real-time. In the .csv file the data is being added every few seconds, I have verified that the data is being written and the .csv is not empty. I then try to use FuncAnimation to plot this data in real-time through a separate script (the writing and plotting are done in separate scripts). While a figure is generated, it is empty and it does not update with time. My code is as stated below:

```
file_path = "/path/to/file.csv"
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('seaborn-v0_8')
index = count()


def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    time = data['time']
    contrast = data['contrast']

    plt.cla()

    plt.plot(10e-6*time[1:], contrast[1:])
    plt.xlabel("Time (ms)")
    plt.ylabel("Contrast")
    
    


ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000, cache_frame_data=False, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

Based on other stackoverflow answers I have tried changing the block parameter for plt.show() but that did not work either. I obtained the following error upon setting `plt.show(block=False)`

```
UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists until you output the Animation using `plt.show()` or `anim.save().
```